# VSCode extension authoring: How to get a file extension from a languageId?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm authoring a VSCode extension and want to create a file in my extension's `context.globalStorageUri` with a `languageId` appropriate file extension. For example, given `languageId = 'javascript'` a valid file extension would be `.js`.

I would prefer to get the information through vs code's APIs rather than a separate npm language to extension mapping package since users may have unknown languages and custom file extensions registered.

According to the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers, each
extension has its configuration specified in an extension specific package.json.

```
 "languages": [{
        "id": "java",
        "extensions": [ ".java", ".jav" ],
        "aliases": [ "Java", "java" ]
    }]
```

I suppose one way would be to iterate through all extension's package.json files and find the "languages" tag, and apply `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("files.associations");` on top of it, but this seems cumbersome, invasive, and error prone.

Is there a more correct way to address this case?

Comment: Do you want to create files with a file extension for a language, but with content that is not correct for that language?

Comment: I assume you are not starting with an actual file, but users can select a language Id and then you create the file?

Comment: Thanks for the good questions.  I am pulling the languageID from the editor window's current document.  When I run a command, I want to create a new file for that language ID with the correct languageId extension in my extension's directory.  What keeps me from using OpenTextDocument() with the languageId parameter is that the user would then have to navigate to my extension's directory and save it themselves.

Comment: Then you can use the `fileName` property  of the `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.fileName` and then `path.extname(<your FileName>)` to get the extension.  Import/requiire path.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think that may be the best solution. Correct me if I'm wrong, this requires the file to have been saved once?  If so, I can prompt the user to save the file if unsaved before proceeding with the command.

Comment: hey @codeconfessions, did you find a better solution? I'm trying to do this for untitled files, which have no file extensions.